# Regex string doesn't contain 2 dots in a row

Tags: regex

I'd like to know if this regex expression is correct for checking that a string doesn't start with a dot, doesn't end with a dot and contains at least one dot anywhere but not the start or end:

My issue is that I can't figure on how to check if there's 2 dots in a row.

**/^([^.])+([.])+.*([^.])$/**

Comment: Use this website to test your regex https://regex101.com/

Comment: which programming language do you use?  there could be easier solution..

Comment: *"I'd like to know if this regex expression is correct"* -- there is only one way to know if it is correct or not (given that you didn't mention the program or language you want to use it with): pass it to the target program and see if it does what you want.

Comment: I'm using PHP sorry! But I want to know how to make so a string cannot have 2 dots in a row, so for example "test..test" wouldn't be acceptable but test.test would be acceptable.

Comment: @tempestor: See my answer for a solution that works exactly as you need. Use `if (preg_match('~^[^.]+(?:\.[^.]+)+$~', $s, $matches)) { /* VALID! */ }`. The 3rd `$matches`  argument is actually not necessary.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you need to use

```
^[^.]+(?:\.[^.]+)+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/imGKOF/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^.]+` - 1+ chars other than a `.` (so, the first char cannot be `.`)
- `(?:\.[^.]+)+` - 1 or more (thus, the dot inside a string is *obligatory* to appear at least once) sequences of:

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `[^.]+` - 1+ chars other than `.` (the `+` quantifier makes a char other than `.` appear at least once after a dot, thus, making it impossible to match the string with 2 dots on end)
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: would `^[^.]+(?:\.{0,x}[^.]+)+$` that not fix the 'must have .' problem? where x is max consecutive dots?

Comment: @user3012759: the limiting quantifier is redundant here because we need to match `.` *once* between 2 non-`.` symbols.

Comment: Ah, yes you're right OP asked about at least one, so yes your solution is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

You're close, have a try with:

```
^[^.]+(?:\.[^.]+){2,}$
```

It maches strings that have 2 or more dot, but not at the begining or at the end.

If you want one or more dot:

```
^[^.]+(?:\.[^.]+)+$
```

If you want one or two dots:

```
^[^.]+(?:\.[^.]+){1,2}$
```